# Android HTML app: How to use WebViewAssetLoader to allow for multiple JS files?

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview

I am developing an android app with HTML5 canvas, CSS, and JavaScript, using WebView. All content is stored locally on the device. I have made a simple, working app using this short [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2dL6B77Q9A4). The bare-bones app contains just two files (apart from HTML, CSS, and JS):

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.myappname;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);

        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webview"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I expanded the app to include several JS files, I ran into CORS errors due to the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63054818/websetting-allowfileaccessfromfileurls-is-deprecated-in-api-level-30) it appears that the flag `allowFileAccessFromFileURLs` is deprecated, and according to the official Android documentation you now have to use `WebViewAssetLoader` to load local content safely. The [documentation](https://developer.android.google.cn/guide/webapps/load-local-content) on loading in-app content with WebViewAssetLoader provides several code snippets to demonstrate how it is done, this being the first:

```
private static class LocalContentWebViewClient extends WebViewClientCompat {

    private final WebViewAssetLoader mAssetLoader;

    LocalContentWebViewClient(WebViewAssetLoader assetLoader) {
        mAssetLoader = assetLoader;
    }

    @Override
    @RequiresApi(21)
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view,
                                     WebResourceRequest request) {
        return mAssetLoader.shouldInterceptRequest(request.getUrl());
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") // to support API < 21
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view,
                                     String url) {
        return mAssetLoader.shouldInterceptRequest(Uri.parse(url));
    }
}
```

I am an experienced developer, but this is my first Android project, and I have no prior experience with Java or Kotlin. The documentation does not provide a lot of context and assumes that the reader knows where to place the snippets. I need some guidance on where to place the code, and how to use it.

Comment: Hi @h4tt3n did you solve the problem? How?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Currently, I am circumventing the issue by keeping all js code in one file. KISS.

Answer (score 0):

quite late, but still: you CAN load local files via http(s): using WebViewAssetLoader

see the example at https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/webkit/WebViewAssetLoader, it loads local resources from https://appassets.androidplatform.net, which is NOT a real host but serves your local files.